# Difference mapply and .mapply

Tags: r, apply

I was trying to find out info about .mapply but did not find any good explanation. So could anyone explain the difference between mapply and .mapply?

Example:
Why does 
`.mapply(cbind,mylist,NULL)` 
works but not:

```
mapply(cbind,mylist,NULL)
```

?

```
    mylist=list(list(data.frame(a=3,b=2,c=4),data.frame(d=5,e=6,h=8),data.frame(k=2,e=3,b=5,m=5)),
                  list(data.frame(a=32,b=22,c=42),data.frame(d=5,e=63,h=82),data.frame(k=2,e=33,b=5,m=5)),
                  list(data.frame(a=33,b=21,k=41,c=41),data.frame(d=5,e=61,h=80),data.frame(k=22,e=3,b=5,m=5)))

?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?.mapply` :

> .mapply is ‘bare-bones’ versions for use in other R packages.

So .mapply is just a simple (less parameters) version of `mapply` to use in your own package. Indeed `mapply` call internally `.mapply` and then do some result simplification.

```
mapply <- 
function (FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    dots <- list(...)
    answer <- .mapply(FUN, dots, MoreArgs) 
    ## ...
    ## the rest of the function is to simplify the result 

}
```

#### UPDATE after OP edit

```
mapply(cbind,mylist,NULL)
```

does not work because `NULL` here is considered as dots arguments and not the `MoreArgs` parameter. Indeed you reproduce the same error with `.mapply` using :

```
 .mapply(cbind,list(mylist,NULL),NULL)
```

You can avoid this error in `mapply` if you explicitly write the argument name ;

```
 mapply(cbind,mylist,MorgeArgs=NULL)
```

But due to a the line in `mapply` :

```
dots <- list(...)
```

You will not get the same result as with `.mapply`

Finally, if you want just to `unlist`  you nested list , better here to use something like :

```
lapply(mylist,unlist)   # faster and you you get the same output as .mapply
```

Comment: See my specific example I did add. What is the difference there?

Comment: thanks. But `lapply(mylist,unlist)` and `.mapply(cbind,mylist,NULL)` give different results...